# Convert bin/cue image to iso format on OS X?

Tags: dvd, cd-burning

How can I convert an .bin/.cue image to .iso format? ... preferably free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can bring the image into Disk Utility, use the convert option.  Choose CD/DVD master, it will save as a .cdo.  Rename to .iso.

Comment: @mspasov Yeah, *shrug*.  I don't know what the .cdo format really is, but I suspect it's a .bin.  Worked for me in the past, so...

Comment: Disk Utility 15.0 (1511.3) won't open the bin or the cue. They are grayed out in the file open dialog.

Answer (score 26):

A nice tool is [**bchunk**](http://he.fi/bchunk/) (I have used it under linux) which is available in homebrew.

```
$ brew install bchunk
==> Downloading http://he.fi/bchunk/bchunk-1.2.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> make
/usr/local/Cellar/bchunk/1.2.0: 5 files, 56K, built in 2 seconds
Avatars-MBP:~ avatar$ bchunk a.bin a.cue test
```

Comment: Worked beautifully in 2018.

Comment: Worked flawless in 2021.